# Update values from MYSQL table without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I've build a small login system for a home project,so,when the user do the login,he is redirect to the `userspage.php`.In the page i get some data from my mysql table,but the problem is,one of the values i fetch is display to the user with a button near it,when the user press those button i need to perform an php action to increase the value which is display with the button(as an example==> myvalue = 10 | When the user clicks on the button: myvalue = 11 ).I've already build this part,it is working perfectly,but i need to increase the value and update the mysql column without refreshing the page?I know its possible but every tutorial from the web i've tried doesn't work.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: You need to use ajax for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code has a button which onclick calls updatedb.php and shows its output in div element called 'result'

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateDb()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","updatedb.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


   </head>
    <body>

<button onclick='UpdateDb()'>Update</button>
<p> <span id="result"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Then write updatedb.php

```
<?php
do mysql update here.
and echo the result you want to display.
?>
```

Comment: Man you're incredible,the code works perfectly for me!So many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

AJAX is what you're looking for. Best lib for that is jQuery with it's $.ajax() method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: simply include the jquery lib and do onClick="$.ajax({url:'myscript.php?some=param&another=param'})"

Comment: Thanks for your help but Anil provided the perfect code for me!