# when reloading page containing a table with mysql data, it should go to a specific part of the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

So my table contains a button in every row.
The purpose of the button is to update that certain row, whenever it is clicked. And i have to reload the whole table to do this (SELECT * FROM table).

My problem is that the table is so long that when you reload the page, you have to scroll down to see if how 
the row is updated. I want to scroll it to a particular submit button when the page is reloaded.

I might want to use javascript and however i am new to it. 
I have seen ajax functionality in this link but i can't seem to implement it, because i don't know how to retrieve values from php file to html. But i can do vice versa, (E.G. xmlhttp.open("GET","updatedb.php?q="+str+"&s"=+str2,true);)
[Update values from MYSQL table without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157586/update-values-from-mysql-table-without-reloading-the-page)

```
if (isset($_POST['lvl'] && isset($_POST['$poke_ID']))
{
   // increment the lvl to +1
   //update the database
}
....
//SELECT ALL
....
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $lvl= $row['lvl'];
  $poke_ID = $row['ID'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['trainer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['skills'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['strength'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['weakness'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lvl'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .<<<_END
<form action="pokemondata.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="lvl" value="$lvl" />
<input type="hidden" name="poke_ID" value="$poke_ID" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
_END;

  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a name="id" attribute on the row and just put "#id" at the end of the URL you are redirecting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just realised my comment wasn't all that helpful so I'll attempt to answer your question.

First of all, have you considered to split the table up into pages? That would speed up pageload and make things easier to find. Secondly, my comment isn't totaly useless.

```
<tr name="<?php echo $poke_ID; ?>">
```

Would give you the option to use a link such as `http://yoursite.tld/page.php#poke_ID` to automatically go the row with the coresponding name. It is expected behaviour of the browser so you should be able to relly on this.

Retrieving data from an AJAX request is described in the link you submitted.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
```

This is a callback function that is called when the request changes state (loading, done loading etc.) and the result (i.e. page data) is stored in `xmlhttp.responseText`.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML
```

Is used to change the HTML within the HTML-element with an id of "result". So you might want to give your table an id and reload it with AJAX. To do this just give your table an id of "result" or better yet something descriptive such as "my_pokemons". Don't forget to update the code accordingly.

```
document.getElementById("my_pokemons").innerHTML
```

You might want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make things easier or just do it like in the example. In any case I would recommend that you read up on javascript. I would recommend [W3CSchool](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) for starters and then searching SO for more practical examples.